# HP ProLiant DL380 G4 and G6?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I currently have a rack mount kit for a HP ProLiant DL380 G4 server however we have a HP ProLiant DL380 G6 server, will a rack mount kit for a HP ProLiant DL380 G4 fit a HP ProLiant DL380 G6 server?

or wil i have to buy a separete mount kit for this server?

Answer (score 0):

Buy the proper equipment for your server.

- The DL380 G4 was introduced in 2004.
- The DL380 G6 was introduced in 2009.

It's a large enough time difference that the physical chassis of the servers has changed. A visual inspection of the two servers in your possession would reveal that.

Your path of least-resistance is to find a [rail kit on ebay using part number 574765-001](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3984.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.X574765-001&_nkw=574765-001&_sacat=0&_from=R40).